# Running Android Support v4 Library Demo Programs

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library

I'm interested in running the Android Support library demo projects for the v4 library.
Using the Android SDK manager I've installed the Eclipse plugins, and APIs from 2.2 to 4.0.1. There are several issues involved, and the sample project as provided is far from running on my configuration, as downloaded.

To reproduce this error:

- Install SDK and Eclipse Juno
- Import the sample v4 compatibility project using File --> New --> New Project and choose "from existing code", targeting, for example, the `Support4Demos` folder in `<Android-sdk-path>/extras/android/support`

[image]

- Open the file `AccessibilityManagerSupportActivity.java`. The following errors appear.

[image]

- Open `res/values-v11/styles.xml`. The following errors occur.
  [image]

How do I get rid of these errors? I'd also like to understand why they are appearing so I can fix them in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check your libs folder has android-support-v4.jar is present or not. if not add this jar file in libs folder

Comment: Thanks for your helpful suggestions around fixing the JAR issue. The issue of "import com.example.android.supportv4.R;" still needs to be resolved.

Comment: I believe you should delete this line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clean solution is to:

- Right-click your project.
- Choose "Android Tools"
- Choose "Add support library".
- Install the appropriate support library (the newest)

I can't really answer you on the why this problem happens, but I'm guessing the Android team doesn't supply the Android support library, because it's changing all the time, so not to get stuck on some older version, they want us to supply it on our own.

If errors still persists or new errors come up, right-click the project again and choose "Android tool" -> "Fix project properties"

**Update:** In conjuction to my answer, the way to remove the rest of the errors is to import the project another way than you did.

- Select File -> New -> Other
- Click Next
- Write Android Sample
- Select Android sample Project and click Next

Now add the Android support librarys as described above.
You will get errors still however. To fix these, do the following:

- Right-click your project and select "Properties"
- Select Android
- Select an SDK version equal to 3.0 or above
- Select Ok and clean the project from the project menu.
- All done ;-)

Now you won't be able to run the sample project on devices lower than Android 3.0.
The reason is because of some dependencies on some themes and settings, that wasn't added before Android 3.0 apparently.

It doesn't make sense why Google did this, but they did. You could try to remove the SDK +11 (Android 3.0) specific dependencies, but it will take some time - there are more errors than you actually see - especially in the XML files.

Comment: This is excellent. Do you have any experience with the problem around this line: "import com.example.android.supportv4.R;"

Comment: I've tried to fix that issue, but it seems like the whole sample project is somehow "borked"... I'll look into this some more, but unless any of the other suggestions have fixed your problem, I guess it would be worth filing a bugreport or something to Google.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the v4 support library.

In order to do that , please follow these steps :

- Select your project.
- Click on **Project** from the menu.
- Select **Properties**.
- Click on **Java Build Path**.
- Select the **Libraries** tab.
- Click on **Add External JARs**.
- Select the **main directory** of the Android SDK that you installed, then go to **extras** -> **android** -> **support** -> **v4** , and then select **android-support-v4.jar** and click on **Open**.
- Click **OK**.

This should remove the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your libs folder has android-support-v4.jar is present or not. if not add this jar file in libs folder.Just copy the android-support-v4.jar from any project and paste it to the libs folder of your project

Answer (score 0):

I spent a whole night on this but can not solve this problem.
I finally solved the by accident: change some file in the demo and save, then change it back, this cleared all the errors. I think when you change some file and save, eclipse build the project and generate the R.java.